# android application has stopped unexpectedly NullPointerException

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, logcat

Im having this "Android application has stopped unexpectedly, please try again" (everytime i run the play class) and it turned out that there is an issue with the NullPointerException but im not quite sure how to fix it...

**the java code**

```
public class play extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private Question currentQuestion;
    private int currentQuestionIndex;
    private ArrayList<Button> questionButton;
    private TextView questionstextview;
    private TextView questionnumber;
    private TextView playerfeedback;
    public TextView displayscore;
    public int score;
    private List<Question> QuestionList;
    private int answerchoice; 
    public static int totalanswer;
    public static int correctanswer;

     @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.play);
            Log.i("playclass", "this is play class running");

            questionButton = new ArrayList<Button>();

            questionButton.add((Button) findViewById (R.id.answerbutton1));
            questionButton.add((Button) findViewById (R.id.answerbutton2));
            questionButton.add((Button) findViewById (R.id.answerbutton3));
            questionButton.add((Button) findViewById (R.id.answerbutton4));
            currentQuestion = null;
            currentQuestionIndex = 0;

            View AnswerButton1 = findViewById(R.id.answerbutton1);
            AnswerButton1.setOnClickListener(this);
            View AnswerButton2 = findViewById(R.id.answerbutton2);
            AnswerButton2.setOnClickListener(this);
            View AnswerButton3 = findViewById(R.id.answerbutton3);
            AnswerButton3.setOnClickListener(this);
            View AnswerButton4 = findViewById(R.id.answerbutton4);
            AnswerButton4.setOnClickListener(this);

            Log.i("playclass", "aftersetlistener");

            QuestionList = new ArrayList<Question>();
            ArrayList <String> answer = new ArrayList<String>();


            answer.add("8");
            answer.add("9");
            answer.add("3");
            answer.add("1");
            QuestionList.add(new Question("what is 4+4", answer, 0));
            answer.add("17");
            answer.add("20");
            answer.add("15");
            answer.add("14");
            QuestionList.add(new Question("what is 7+8?", answer, 3));
            answer.add("20");
            answer.add("30");
            answer.add("19");
            answer.add("34");
            QuestionList.add(new Question("what is 10+10?", answer, 0));
            answer.add("12");
            answer.add("11");
            answer.add("13");
            answer.add("14");
            QuestionList.add(new Question("what is 6+6?", answer, 0));
            answer.add("6");
            answer.add("5");
            answer.add("4");
            answer.add("7");
            QuestionList.add(new Question("what is 4+3?", answer, 3));
            answer.add("7");
            answer.add("9");
            answer.add("10");
            answer.add("11");
            QuestionList.add(new Question("what is 3+7?", answer, 2));

            questionstextview = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.questionstextview);           
            questionnumber = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.questionnumber);        
            displayscore = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.displayscore);

            StartTrivia();
        }

    private void ButtonPress (Button answerButton){

    final MediaPlayer soundfx = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.click);

        soundfx.start();

        for (int i=0; i< questionButton.size(); i++)


            if (questionButton.get(i) ==answerButton)


            if (i==currentQuestion.getAnswerIndex()){

                 score=+5;
                 totalanswer++;
                 correctanswer++;

                displayscore.setText(Integer.toString(score));

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Correct!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

            else{

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Incorrect!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

                currentQuestionIndex++;

                if (currentQuestionIndex < QuestionList.size()){

                    StartTrivia();
                }

                else{

                    Intent result = new Intent (this, finalscreen.class);
                    startActivity(result);
                }
    }

    public void StartTrivia(){

         Log.i("playclass", "running StartTrivia()");

        currentQuestion = QuestionList.get(currentQuestionIndex);
        Log.i("playclass", "after get current question");
        questionstextview.setText(currentQuestion.getquestion());
        Log.i("playclass", "after set current question");
        questionnumber.setText(Integer.toString(currentQuestionIndex+1));
        Log.i("playclass", "after convert int to string for question number");
        for (int i = 0; i < questionButton.size(); i++)

         { 
             questionButton.get(i).setText(currentQuestion.getanswer().get(i));
             Log.i("playclass", "after get question button");
         }

        }


    public play() {

    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    }
}
```

**The LogCat**

```
 I/mainactivity(372): this is Main Activity running<br>
 I/playclass(372): this is play class running<br>
 I/playclass(372): aftersetlistener<br>
 I/playclass(372): running StartTrivia()<br>
 I/playclass(372): after get current question<br>
 I/playclass(372): after set current question<br>
 I/playclass(372): after convert int to string for question number<br>
 D/AndroidRuntime(372): Shutting down VM<br><br><br>

 W/dalvikvm(372): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)<br>
 E/AndroidRuntime(372): FATAL EXCEPTION: main<br>
 E/AndroidRuntime(372): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.quizgame/com.example.quizgame.play}: java.lang.NullPointerException
 E/AndroidRuntime(372): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
 E/AndroidRuntime(372):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
 E/AndroidRuntime(372):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
 E/AndroidRuntime(372):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
 E/AndroidRuntime(372):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)<br>
 E/AndroidRuntime(372):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)<br>
 E/AndroidRuntime(372):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)<br>
 E/AndroidRuntime(372):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)<br>
 E/AndroidRuntime(372):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
 E/AndroidRuntime(372):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)<br><br>


 E/AndroidRuntime(372):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)<br>
 E/AndroidRuntime(372):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)<br>
 E/AndroidRuntime(372): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException<br>
 E/AndroidRuntime(372):     at com.example.quizgame.play.StartTrivia(play.java:157)<br>
 E/AndroidRuntime(372):     at com.example.quizgame.play.onCreate(play.java:98)<br>
 E/AndroidRuntime(372):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)<br>
 E/AndroidRuntime(372):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)<br>
 E/AndroidRuntime(372):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: What line of code is at `com.example.quizgame.play.StartTrivia(play.java:157)`?

Comment: @CommonsWare   questionButton.get(i).setText(currentQuestion.getanswer().get(i));

Comment: Well, then either `questionButton` is `null` or `questionButton.get(i)` is `null`. Try cleaning your project (e.g., Project > Clean in Eclipse) and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have an index problem - is it really the case that this line:

```
questionButton.get(i).setText(currentQuestion.getanswer().get(i));
```

should have the index of the "questionButton" be the same as the index of "getanswer()" for the current question? What is the size of the answer array? It's probably getanswer() does not have as many elements as questionButton

Answer (score 0):

In the 11th line of the onCreate method you initialized the currentQuestion object to null and you never changed it